# Get first word of extracted value in Imacros /split/

Tags: split, imacros

I'm really dumb to javascript and i can't get trough this simple task.
I want to get the first word of a string, this is what i have so far:

```
set !var1 eval("var s=\"{{!EXTRACT}}\"; var n = s.split(" ", 1);")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
SET !VAR1 EVAL("var s=\"{{!EXTRACT}}\"; s.split(' ')[0];")
```